# Preg_replace cyrillic word or phrase - not both

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am writing a PHP function which is supposed to convert certain keywords into links. It uses Cyrillic words in UTF-8.
So I came up with this:

```
function keywords($text){

    $keywords = Db::get('keywords'); //array with words and corresponding links
    foreach ($keywords as $value){
        $keyword = $value['keyword'];
        $link = $value['link'];
        $text = preg_replace('/(?<!\pL)('.$keyword.')(?!\pL)/iu', '<a href='.$link.' class="linked">$1</a>', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

So far this runs like a charm, but now I want to replace phrases with links - phrases that may contain other keywords. For example I want the word "car" to link to one place, and "blue car" to other.

Any ideas?

Comment: If there are not very many keywords, you can first try to sort them by number of spaces from greater to lesser.

Comment: I thought about that but I think  that will replace “blue car” with <a href=”some_site.com”>blue car</a>, and then again “car” …
The result  will be something like:
<a href=”some_site.com”>blue<a href=”some_other_site.com”> car</a></a>

Comment: You could try replacing them first with a placeholder, and then, when entire text is parsed, substitute the placeholders with the real words. For example:
phrase: "i have a car, a blue car."
after first parsing (check "blue car"): "i have a car, a [[1]]."
after second parsing (check "car"): "i have a [[2]], a [[1]]."
then, when all keywords have been substituted, you just replace the placeholders in their order using the `preg_replace` in your function, and get the text with links. Is it something useful?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but you should use [preg_quote](http://uk3.php.net/preg-quote) for `$keyword`.

Comment: Excellent idea,
I’ll give it a try right away.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment, i post this as an answer, hoping it's been useful to you.

You could try replacing the keyword into the text firstly by using a placeholder and then, when entire text has been parsed, you can substitute those placeholders with the real words.

For example, take the phrase:

```
"I have a car, a blue car."
```

We already ordered the keywords list from longer to smaller, so we get to check "blue car"; We find it in the text, so we put the placeholder and obtain:

```
"I have a car, a [[1]]."
```

The second keyword in the list is "car"; after substitution in the text, we obtain:

```
"I have a [[2]], a [[1]]."
```

Finally, when all keywords have been substituted, you only have to replace the placeholders in their order using the preg_replace in your function, and get the text with links.